# Require help in C# Need to implement moving picture box

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need a help on this,

> There are 3 picture boxes, red should grow its Width to left, green should grow its height to top blue's width to right
>
> also if one reaches the top border / any text boxes it should give an error / stop execution
>
> I need to add more picture boxes in future and  if two of them collides it should give an error / stop execution. I have managed to code them to go up, however unable to get other functions working. Please some one help me with this.

OR

https://www.box.com/s/d0d302c6c266f52e0abf

Thank you.
RR

My code below,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadwithmovingPicbxmoving
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread t1;
        Thread t2;
        Thread t3;

        delegate void CTMethod(int val);
        delegate void CTFinish(string t);
        Queue<string> order = new Queue<string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int y = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            int g = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

            t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(loopred));
            t2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(loopyel));
            t3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(loopGree));

            t1.Start(r);
            t2.Start(y);
            t3.Start(g);

        }
        private void updateRed(int val)
        {
            pictureBox1.Height = val;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }

        private void updateyell(int val)
        {
            pictureBox2.Height = val;
            pictureBox2.Refresh();
        }
        private void updategree(int val)
        {
            pictureBox3.Height = val;
            pictureBox3.Refresh();

        }

        private void loopred(object o)
        {
            int c = (int)o;
            CTMethod ctred = new CTMethod(updateRed);
            if (c < 500)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
                {
                    this.Invoke(ctred, i);
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a value less than 500 for Red Box!!!");
            }
            CTFinish CTFin = new CTFinish(Threadfinish);
            this.Invoke(CTFin, "Red");
        }

        private void loopyel(object o)
        {
            int c = (int)o;
            CTMethod ctyell = new CTMethod(updateyell);
            if (c < 500)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
                {
                    this.Invoke(ctyell, i);
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a valure less than 500 for Yellow Box!!!");
            }
            CTFinish CTFin = new CTFinish(Threadfinish);
            this.Invoke(CTFin, "Yell");
        }


        private void loopGree(object o)
        {
            int c = (int)o;
            CTMethod ctgree = new CTMethod(updategree);
            if (c < 500)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
                {
                    this.Invoke(ctgree, i);
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a valure less than 500 for Green Box!!!");
            }
            CTFinish CTfin = new CTFinish(Threadfinish);
            this.Invoke(CTfin, "Green");

        }

        private void Threadfinish(string t)
        {
            order.Enqueue(t);
            if (order.Count == 3)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Threads finished in this order: \n" + "1." + order.Dequeue() + "\n" + "2." + order.Dequeue()
                    + "\n" + "3." + order.Dequeue() + "\n", "finished");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into it. I want the picture boxes to grow to one side only, yah its a kind of moving or growing to one side, The red one should grow to the Left side, Green to the top and blue to right side. And I am going to add more boxes if some of the collied I need to stop execution / some error.

Comment: The text boxes where u enter how long the picture boxes should grow.. there are 3 boxes for 3 picture boxes.. the rest 2 you can ignore them as they are for different use.. It uses a threading to grow them simultaneously.

Comment: It is simple with three pictureboxes. But with Dynamic number of pictureboxes you have to change the code each time you add or remove a pictureBox.

Comment: Okie. But how you do that, I tried pictureBox1.Location.X == pictureBox2.Location.X for collision detection but did not seems to work.. and also I am unable to get picture box to grow right side..

Comment: This is just my project to test a functionality.. I want the threading part to be exactly like that..

Comment: Right Then Its Ok. Try The following code as instructed and Report for any problem

Comment: Sure will do that right away.. Thank you so much..

Comment: Sorry commenting more may close this post. So Just Try the Latest Code and comment only on answer not here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try It. Its All Fine with three PictureBoxes

Create New Widows Application with name help and then replace Form1.cs code with Following

Run It. It also includes values from TextBoxes

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace help
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Thread t1;
    Thread t2;
    Thread t3;

    delegate void CTMethod(int val);
    delegate void CTFinish(string t);
    Queue<string> order = new Queue<string>();


    #region Variables of Designer File
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    #endregion


    public Form1()
    {
        #region Designer Code I have Cut and Pasted Here
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.pictureBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.pictureBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox2)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox3)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);

        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(161, 268);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // pictureBox2
        // 
        this.pictureBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        this.pictureBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(383, 268);
        this.pictureBox2.Name = "pictureBox2";
        this.pictureBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
        this.pictureBox2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.pictureBox2.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // pictureBox3
        // 
        this.pictureBox3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        this.pictureBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(605, 268);
        this.pictureBox3.Name = "pictureBox3";
        this.pictureBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
        this.pictureBox3.TabIndex = 2;
        this.pictureBox3.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(161, 26);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(383, 25);
        this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textBox2.TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // textBox3
        // 
        this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(605, 26);
        this.textBox3.Name = "textBox3";
        this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
        this.textBox3.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 23);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 6;
        this.button1.Text = "Go";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        this.PerformLayout();
        #endregion

        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.Text = "490";
        textBox2.Text = "490";
        textBox3.Text = "490";

        textBox1.Leave += new EventHandler(textBox1_Leave);
        textBox2.Leave += new EventHandler(textBox2_Leave);
        textBox3.Leave += new EventHandler(textBox3_Leave);
    }

    // To input Only Valid int values in TextBoxes
    #region TextBoxes Input Validation
    int t1Val = 490;
    int t2Val = 490;
    int t3Val = 490;
    void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int t1Val = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
    }
    void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int t2Val = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            textBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
    void textBox3_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int t3Val = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            textBox3.Focus();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int r = t1Val;
        int y = t2Val;
        int g = t3Val;

        t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(loopRed));
        t2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(loopGreen));
        t3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(loopBlue));

        // It will avoid proble if you exit app when threads are working
        t1.IsBackground = true;
        t2.IsBackground = true;
        t3.IsBackground = true;


        t1.Start(r);
        t2.Start(y);
        t3.Start(g);

    }
    private void updateRed(int val)
    {
        pictureBox1.Width++;
        pictureBox1.Left--;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void updateGreen(int val)
    {
        pictureBox2.Height++;
        pictureBox2.Top--;
        pictureBox2.Refresh();
    }
    private void updateBlue(int val)
    {
        pictureBox3.Width++;
        pictureBox3.Refresh();
    }

    private void loopRed(object o)
    {
        int c = (int)o;
        CTMethod ctRed = new CTMethod(updateRed);
        if (c < 500)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                if (pictureBox1.Left > 0)
                {
                    this.Invoke(ctRed, i);
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a value less than 500 for Red Box!!!");
        }
        CTFinish CTFin = new CTFinish(Threadfinish);
        this.Invoke(CTFin, "Red");
    }

    private void loopGreen(object o)
    {
        int c = (int)o;
        CTMethod ctGreen = new CTMethod(updateGreen);
        if (c < 500)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {                    
                if (pictureBox2.Top > 0 && pictureBox2.Top != textBox2.Top + textBox2.Height)
                {
                    this.Invoke(ctGreen, i);
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a valure less than 500 for Green Box!!!");
        }
        CTFinish CTFin = new CTFinish(Threadfinish);
        this.Invoke(CTFin, "Green");
    }


    private void loopBlue(object o)
    {
        int c = (int)o;
        CTMethod ctBlue = new CTMethod(updateBlue);
        if (c < 500)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                if (pictureBox3.Left + pictureBox3.Width < this.Width)
                {
                    this.Invoke(ctBlue, i);
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a valure less than 500 for Blue Box!!!");
        }
        CTFinish CTfin = new CTFinish(Threadfinish);
        this.Invoke(CTfin, "Blue");

    }

    private void Threadfinish(string t)
    {
        order.Enqueue(t);
        if (order.Count == 3)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Threads finished in this order: \n" + "1." + order.Dequeue() + "\n" + "2." + order.Dequeue()
                + "\n" + "3." + order.Dequeue() + "\n", "finished");

        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: That's great, now if add 5 more picture boxes and starts growing then all over how I can tackle if 2 growing picture boxes collide. I want to send an error message / stop execution then.